# Links to resources with friendly URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm trying to write a blog in Rails 3, so I have posts. I want to make nice routes for the posts like this: `posts/year/month/day/post-title`. So I overrided to_param in `model/post.rb` and use `friendly_id` for title:

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, :use => :slugged

def to_param
  "#{year}/#{month}/#{day}/#{title.parameterize}"
end
```

And I added this to `routes.rb`:

```
resources :posts do
  collection do
    match ":year/:month/:day/:id", :action => "show"
  end
  member do
    post 'comment'
    delete 'comment/:comment_id', :action => 'destroy_comment', :as => 'destroy_comment'
  end
end
```

In `show` this works:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("/images/edit_icon.png"),            
    { :controller => 'posts', :action => 'edit' }, :id => @post %>
```

But in `index` it says

```
routing error:
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"}.
```

I'm new to Rails and I haven't managed to find out what causes this error. Can anyone help me figure out what I do wrong?